# Sql server I Want make Stored Procedure to Take Table Name in Runtime and return Last row in This Table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a stored procedure to achieve the following in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spByTableNameReturnLastRowNew]
    @tableName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SelectLastRow NVARCHAR(100)

    SET @SelectLastRow = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)+ ' ORDER BY AutoNo DESC'

    EXECUTE(@SelectLastRow)

    RETURN 
END
```

it is work but when calling it by entity framework the result Variable return INT datatype I want to return row (object) to use data not int.

This is the code using the stored procedure in Entity Framework:

```
var result = milestoneArhEntities.spByTableNameReturnLastRowNew(TableName);
```

Comment: This won't work. 

* The return value of a stored procedure is always an integer. This is a completely different thing to a resultset selected from a stored procedure. 
* `var` is a compile time instruction for the compiler to work out what type a variable is and bake that type into the compiled program; you can't vary it at runtime
* Entity Framework is intended to map C# objects to database side rows, and for that a consistent mapping is required. If you're returning a differently shaped row all the time, you're going to struggle. 

Using Dapper would probably be easier

Comment: use SQLQuery or make a temporary table in the procedure and then use that table in EF model

Comment: Thank you, if i want Stored Procedure to Take Table Name in Runtime and return Last row in This Table what do ?

Comment: It might work with something more like `var result = context.TableNameEntity.FromSqlInterpolated($"spByTableNameReturnLastRowNew '{TableName}', ")` but your result is typed at compile time. Might have to use generics if youre trying to write a single C# side method that returns any entity

Comment: Why do you (think you) need to retrieve the last row from any table? It's almost always a bad idea - e.g. if you need to find what identity value it was assigned, there are better ways. If you're trying to implement identity yourself, there are better ways, etc.

Comment: And bear in mind that it's unusual to build a system that only supports one user - if you've got multiple users, you've got no guarantee of how the current last row in the table relates to either recent inserts or any future ones for one specific user.

Comment: I want to return the last row depending on the column identity in Table

Comment: @marc_s in OP's defence: there is a presumably consistent ordering shown in the SP: `ORDER BY AutoNo DESC`, which I presume is actually an `IDENTITY` or similar

Answer (score 0):

The ORM here needs to understand (in advance) the table layout in order to interpret result grids as objects. Because of this, you can't really do:

```cs
var result = milestoneArhEntities.spByTableNameReturnLastRowNew(TableName);
```

because the ORM *can't possibly know what that means*; an *individual* method can usually be configured to return, say, a `Order` (or `List<Order>`) or a `Customer` (or `List<Customer>`) etc, but that doesn't really help you here since the table structure is defined solely by the `tableName` parameter.

There's no good way to do what you want here, but I'm not convinced that what you want is a useful thing *anyway*, in the general sense. I'm also not sure that an SP is doing much for you here, compared to inline SQL.

You *could* write multiple methods i.e.

```cs
var customer = milestoneArhEntities.GetLastCustomer();
var order = milestoneArhEntities.GetLastOrder();
```

with them being table/class specific. The ORM should be fine with that.